# php composer can't accessed inside public_html folder

Tags: php, bash, laravel, ssh, composer-php

I installed composer inside my server. Here is what my files look like via ssh

[image]

When i type composer from here it is working, but when i navigate inside public_html folder and type composer it is responding as `-bash: composer: command not found` like this.

What should i do to make composer accessible from public_html folder too

Comment: Provide the full path to the folder where composer is defined? Move composer to /user/sbin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the absolute path. It looks like `composer` is your home directory, so this should work:

```
~/composer
```

Another solution is to add the directory to your `PATH`.
However, you not install software in your home directory.
Install composer at a better location,
recommended by your operating system.
Then, that directory is likely to be already on `PATH`,
so simply running `composer` will work everywhere.

Comment: It works awesome.. Will accept in 10 min, thanks you saved me :)